# ClassNotFound Error While Reading Object (Tomcat)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, classpath

I will try to explain this to the best of my abilities! I have a war and jar created using maven. The JAR package is contains some common classes that is to be used by other war files as well. So I am trying to initialize log4j 2 objects and fetch some values from the log4j configuration XML. I have added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In the pom files of both the WAR and the JAR. So I create a LoggerContext object in one of the war file's classes. And then the objects passes to one of the classes in the JAR file.

```
LoggerContext loggerContext  = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        String configFilePath = servletContext.getRealPath(WebInit.getProperty("log4jPropertiesFileName"));
        File loggingConfigFile = new File(configFilePath);

        loggerContext.setConfigLocation(loggingConfigFile.toURI()); 

        log = new RunningLog(loggerContext, logHostName,  "MyAPP", "ALL", "MyAPP", "MyAPP");
```

The class RunningLog resides in the JAR file. So when the I try to do anything with the loggerContext object, I get an error:

```
04-Nov-2019 13:45:07.852 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [InitialiseMyAPP] in web application [/MyAPP] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

The line throwing the exception is:

```
setOracleSchema(loggerContext.getConfiguration().getStrSubstitutor().getVariableResolver().lookup("Schema"));
```

I have placed the JAR file in Tomcat's lib folder and the WAR file in the webapps folder. First I thought I need to add the log4j jars separately in the lib folder. So I tried that too. But that throws a LinkageError when I try to run it. If you have questions/clarifications please let me know. Any help on this would be appreciated. Struggling for two days with this!

Comment: Is there a reason you're putting the jar file (not file**S**?) into `/tomcat/lib` instead of keeping them inside the war file?

Comment: Let me know about the Tomcat and Java version you're using, please.

Comment: @Kayman If i do that, will the objects created in the JAR be shareable? If I create the an object from A.war, will B.war be able to access its values?

Comment: @AhmadR.Sedighi I am using Tomcat 9.0.27 and JDK 1.8

Comment: The only thing i can say is that I had the JAR file added as a dependency with scope "provided". But when I changed it to compile, it started working. But now the objects don't persist the value from one war to the other.